# error with yield - "function" object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a heater function but I am having a few difficulties. I am fairly new to Python.

I want my heater to run for 15000 seconds but for the first 120 seconds (inclusive of 120). I want it to follow a linear path Temperatures = 0.0804 * time + 16.081 and then after 120 seconds I want it to remain constant for the rest of the remaining time at the final temperature found from the linear equation. I need to calculate the temperature for each given time individually. As the finite element code I am putting my code into calls python at each time step and only wants the information for that time step.

The code I have written is below which I am getting errors saying 'function' object is not subscriptable

```
    import math, numpy as np
from random import *

a = 0.0804

def temperatures():
    for second in xrange(121):
            last = a * second + 18.3
        yield last

mygenerator = temperatures() #create a generator
print(mygenerator)
for last in mygenerator:
    temperatures += temperatures[120:] * (15000 - 120)
    print temperatures
```

I know that the error is to do with line 14. I think I can't call a `temperatures[120:]` because it is not a list or a dictionary? I am not sure really what is the best way to write what I need in python. I need to calculate the temperature for each given time individually. As the finite element code I am putting my code into  calls python at each time step and only wants the information for that time step.

Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: What does the `temperatures[120:]` stands for? I really cannot tell what should be the expected output. You are using `temperatures` as a function *and* as a list/number(something that supports `+=`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here.

First, you iterator will only run for 120 cycles, then it will end, which isn't what you've described above. Next, you aren't referencing the output of the generator. You should refer to last if you want the output.

Below is a very simplified generator that performs something similar to what you are looking at doing. It runs for 10 cycles, but behaves differently after the first 5.

```
>>> def Temp():
...     for i in xrange(10):
...             if i<5:
...                     yield i;
...             else:
...                     yield 5
... 
>>> for last in Temp():
...     print last
```